# mapping string values with corresponding formats

Tags: java

I have to process many strings( thousands ) which are in  either of the two formats as below:

```
============= Examples of Str=============
123|S|122.14, 
S,344,122.146 

==============================================
The format of these strings are 
A|B|C 
B,A,C
```

I want them as `A=123 B=S C=122.14`

and `A=344`, `B=S`, `C=122.146`   ( where A , B , C correspond to column names and can be loaded into  sql server db )

How do I do this.

I can use split to get the substrings as values. How do I map these values with formats and load them?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
String str = "123|S|122.14,";
String[] tokens = str.split("[|,]");
String A;
String B;
String C;
if(tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
{
    A = tokens[1];
    B = tokens[0];
    C = tokens[2];
}
else            
{
    A = tokens[0];
    B = tokens[1];
    C = tokens[2];
}
```

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: You are right. I missed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ABC; 
if( line.contains( '|' ) ) {
   ABC = str.split( "|" ); 
} else {
   String[] split = str.split( "," ); 
   ABC = new Object[] { split[1], split[0], split[2] ); 
}
```

Comment: And then 
String A = ABC[0], B=ABC[1], C=ABC[2]
if you prefer.